# Disable JPA query cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, caching

I have a Java EE program which runs on a WildFly 9 server. In this program I want to record in database thousands of records in once. That's why in my method I use a native query:

```
public int record(Collection<MyEntity> entities) {

    /**
     * Following query is something like:
     * INSERT INTO my_table (id, date, value) VALUES
     *   (1, '2016-02-24', 10),
     *   (2, '2016-02-23', 8),
     *   ...
     *   (10000, '2016-02-01', 6);
     */

    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO my_table (id, date, value) VALUES ");

    for (int i = 1; i <= entities.size(); i++) {
        queryString.append("?,?,?)");
        if (i < parameters.size()) {
            queryString.append(',');
        }
    }

    Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryString.toString());
    int parameterPosition = 0;
    for (MyEntity entity : entities) {
        query.setParameter(++parameterPosition, entity.getId());
        query.setParameter(++parameterPosition, entity.getDate());
        query.setParameter(++parameterPosition, entity.getValue());
    }

    return query.executeUpdate();

}
```

My problem is `Hibernate` keeps in cache some (I don't know how many) prepared statements. For example if I have one entity in my collection, the query `INSERT INTO my_table (id, date, value) VALUE (?,?,?)` will be cached, for two entities it will be `INSERT INTO my_table (id, date, value) VALUE (?,?,?),(?,?,?)` and so on. As I said I want to record thousands of records, so big strings are cached and after a while my application crash with the ugly `java heap space` error.

So I wonder if it's possible to disable cache for this particular query ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is 'caching of the statements' that causes the issue?

Comment: Yes I'm absolutely sure.

Comment: Mind posting your research about it, it may help others to provide a more accurate answer.